# Could not find @PathVariable in @RequestMapping

Tags: spring-mvc, controller, request

I have a problem when running project. page and controller configure right. But when I add @RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET) his throw exception.

```
NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvocationException: Failed to invoke handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.solution.controller.BookListController.edit(java.lang.String,org.springframework.ui.Model)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find @PathVariable [id] in @RequestMapping
```

Help me. Why this problem is throwed?
Page work when I comment "edit" and  "delete" methods

My Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/BookList.vw")
public class BookListController {

    @Autowired
    private IBookService bookService;


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    protected ModelAndView openMain(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        List<Book> books = bookService.listBooks();
        model.put("books", books);

        return new ModelAndView("BookList", "model", model);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView edit(@PathVariable String id, Model model) {
        Map<String, Object> models = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        models.put("id", id);
        return new ModelAndView("EditBook", "model", models);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/delete/{id}"})
    public ModelAndView delete(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        bookService.removeBook(id);
        return new ModelAndView(getModelName());
    }
}
```

My page fragment:

```
 <c:forEach items="${model.books}" var="book">
        <tr align="left" height="100%">
            <td>${book.name}</td>
            <td>${book.description}</td>
            <td>${book.year}</td>
            <td></td>
                <%--<td>${book.authorNames}</td>--%>
            <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
                <td>
                    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/BookList.vw/edit/${book.id}">Edit</a>
                    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/BookList.vw/delete/${book.id}">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </sec:authorize>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 2):

it seems like you have forget the declaration in your method head, please take a look:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/BookList.vw")
public class BookListController {
    ...

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView edit(@PathVariable("id") String id, Model model) {
        Map<String, Object> models = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        models.put("id", id);
        return new ModelAndView("EditBook", "model", models);
    }
...
}
```

Comment: in your edit Method you use the Pathvariable annotation but you missing in this annotation the name of the variable, please compare my with yours. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView edit(@PathVariable String id, Model model) {
    Map<String, Object> models = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    models.put("id", id);
    return new ModelAndView("EditBook", "model", models);
}
```

1) for example instead of call ..../edit/005... you are trying  .../edit.. you missing your id that's why you getting could not find @PathVariable

2)else use Optional in @PathVarible ... (eg.@PathVarible Optional  id)